# Rails Self Referential has_many :through - I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but it isn't right :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, self-reference

I'm trying to set up a self-referential relationship, as described in this great video - http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association - and it's *mostly* working, but not *entirely* working.

I have these entities: Users, who can either be a mentor or a mentee; Matches, which have a mentor_id (user.id), mentee_id (user.id), and status_id; and Statuses, which are a plain lookup table.

My User model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   

has_many :matches
has_many :mentors, :through => :matches
has_many :mentees, :through => :matches
has_many :statuses, :through => :matches

end
```

My Status model looks like this:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
end
```

My Match model looks like this:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :mentee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :status 
end
```

When I **puts user.mentors** I get **SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: matches.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "matches" ON "users".id = "matches".mentor_id WHERE (("matches".user_id = 1))**

Simply, I was hoping to do **user.matches.find(1).status.id** .. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match_mentors, :foreign_key => "mentee_id", :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :match_mentees, :foreign_key => "mentor_id", :class_name => "Match"

  has_many :mentors, :through => :match_mentors
  has_many :mentees, :through => :match_mentees

  def status_with_mentee mentee_id
    match = match_mentees.find_by_mentee_id(mentee_id)
    return nil if match.nil? 
    match.status
  end
end


class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :mentee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :status

  after_create :set_status

  def set_status
   Status.find(1).matches << self #replace 1 with the id you want
  end
end
```

Which gives:

```
u = User.create
u.mentors               => [] 
u.mentors.create        => #<User id: 2, name: nil, created_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17", updated_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17"> 
u.mentors               => [#<User id: 2, name: nil, created_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17", updated_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17">] 
v = u.mentors.first     => #<User id: 2, name: nil, created_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17", updated_at: "2011-06-17 19:02:17"> 
v.mentees               => [#<User id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2011-06-17 18:58:44", updated_at: "2011-06-17 18:58:44">]
```

EDIT, to associate a mentee:

```
current_user.mentees << User.find(params[:mentee_id])
```

Rails will handle everything properly.

To know which is the relation between a mentor and one of his mentees:

```
current_user.status_with_mentee(params[:mentee_id])
```

Of course, you can create the same for mentor relationship

Comment: That totally makes sense and the exception stopped, which is great. But I would have thought I could then reference user.mentors.status.id successfully; it can't find the status method on user.

Comment: I skipped this part. I can't understand: why Status has_many :matches? The status should only represent the link between two people no?

Comment: moreover, if status is like "pending", "confirmed" etc... you shouldn't use another table unless you consider this statuses names may change but that's very unlikely. Indeed it's an old debate in db architecture.

Comment: Status represents a link between two people. But A can have a status with B (pending), and A can have a status with C (expired).

Comment: I'm also storing a description of the status in the database so I can easily change it.. but I hear you.  ultimately, I just want to be able to display a user's status with the dot syntax...

Comment: Right but in this case, every link has it's own and only status. It's a one-one relationship

Comment: Ok, so how do you create the statuses? I guess in a before_create callback in the Match model?

Comment: Yes: **@match = current_user.matches.build(:mentee_id => params[:mentee_id], :mentor_id => current_user.id, :status_id => 1)**

Comment: By adding the has_many Matches to Status, this all works beautifully.

Comment: indeed, just edited the answer to make your code the Rails way

Answer (score 1):

In order to use **user.mentors** You need a

```
belongs_to :user
```

in your Match model so that it knows which user it's tied to.

(your matches table will also need a user_id)

Comment: I don't think it's what the asker is looking for. The mentor/mentee structure should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `User` model don't know what `Match` records to fetch. In your `User` model, you tell it that it `has_many :matches`, so it assumes there's a `user_id` column in your `matches` table. But in your `matches` table, you've only got `mentor_id` and `mentee_id`.

You need to tell us what you're trying to do. Do you want to fetch *all* matches that a user appear in, regardless if it's as a mentor or a mentee? Or does a use only "have" a match if he's mentor in it? Or mentee?

**Possible solution**

If what you want is that `User.first.matches` should return all the matches a user appear in, both as mentee and mentor, this is a possible solution.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def matches
    Match.where("mentor_id = :id OR mentee_id = :id", { :id => self.id })
  end

  def mentors
    User.joins("INNER JOIN matches ON matches.mentor_id = users.id").where("matches.mentee_id = ?", self.id)
  end

  def mentees
    User.joins("INNER JOIN matches ON matches.mentee_id = users.id").where("matches.mentor_id = ?", self.id)
  end
end
```

Keep your other models as is. This will make you able to do `User.first.matches`, `User.first.matches.find(1).status.id`, `User.first.mentors.first.mentees` etc.

If anyone knows how to keep the associations and still retrieve matches where the user appear as both mentor and mentee, I would like to now as well.

Comment: maybe my solution answers your needs